# Increasing hvac flow on return or supply

Tags: hvac

I have an office in the corner of my home that is as far from the HVAC system, on the same floor, as possible. The air flow is pretty weak and I have two computers and 3 larger monitors that make that room 9-10 degrees warmer than the rest of the floor.

Even with the doors open the air flow is not enough to chill it.

I’ve thought about trying to boost the air flow with a supply fan but I also thought about trying to force some of the air out by pushing air in the return.

For all the HVAC folks, what’s the best way to increase the overall air circulation?

Btw I have the Honeywell controller set to constant fan.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partially or completely close some of the other vents that will force more air in you pace.

Without changing the heat exchanger fan to higher CFM you can not get more air flow in your home. You get bit more if you take out the air return filter, but that is not very good solution.

The heat exchanger fan is responsible for circulating the air in your home. It sucks it up on air returns (with filters) forces the air over the cold coil and blows it back into home.

Check if any furniture is blocking the air return.

Comment: I remember reading that closing the vents can also cause issues with the HVAC not getting enough air flow and the coils having issues.  Is that something only with older units?

Comment: Closing off vents in other rooms, @zmanc, will give the air no place to go except through the open vents. Since there will be open vents in your office, they'll get stronger air flow. Many high-end HVAC systems will have automated dampers in the duct work to accomplish exactly this. If you find it works well, you might consider installing some ($$$$) to help balance the temperature throughout your house.